# VS2017 property sheet replacement issue

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Some time ago I wrote a point cloud drop sampling code, directly call someone else's library "Library111" and property sheet.However, since the property sheet was not working well, the library was deleted and a new library named "Library_original" was copied.
During this period of time, the code of point cloud drop sampling was suddenly needed, so I changed the property sheet contained in the project to the property sheet in "Library_original", but I was warned that a file in the library "Library111" could not be found. I checked the included directory and library directory in the property sheet, and the path has been updated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, you should check if the path is right.

If the file from `D:\Library111\pcldebug_vs2017.props` exists and there is no spelling errors under the path.

You should use this under the `vcxproj` file:

```
<Import Project="D:\Library111\pcldebug_vs2017.props"/>
```

**After** that, close VS, restart your project to test again.

The right way use to

```
<Import Project="D:\Library_original\pcldebug_vs2017.props"/>
```

Comment: I changed "Library111" to "Library_original", the error dispeared!.Did i miss something when i change my property?i just changed property and file path in it.